is there a way to only display dots for individual data points on a boxplot if they are above/below a certain range?
I would like to create a boxplot for my data where the boxplot itself represents the IQR and the whiskers represent the 5th to 95th percentile values. I want to use geom_dotplot to only show the individual data points that lie above or below the whiskers (ie below 5th percentile or above 95th percentile). Is there a way to do this using ggplot in R?

I don't want the dots that are within the boxplot to be visible, only those above/below the whiskers.

Please, share your code, so that it is easier for us to help you ☺️

You can set the values of the whiskers and hinges to whatever you like using stat = "identity" inside geom_boxplot. Just use quantile to precalculate the values you want. Filter the data set to create a second little data frame for the points.
You didn't provide a reproducible example, so I will assume your dataframe has columns called "x" and "y". Here's a reproducible data set to demonstrate:
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B"), y = rnorm(100, 4.5, 2))

Now we can do:
library(tidyverse)

box <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(mn = quantile(y, 0.05), 
            low = quantile(y, 0.25),
            mid = median(y),
            up = quantile(y, 0.75),
            mx = quantile(y, 0.95))

points <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(lo = quantile(y, 0.05), hi = quantile(y, 0.95)) %>%
  filter(y < lo | y > hi)
  
ggplot(box, aes(x, fill = x)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = mn, lower = low, middle = mid, upper = up, ymax = mx),
               stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y), data = points) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray90", "gray75"), guide = "none") +
  theme_classic(20)


